# How to get metadata ( MaxWidth, MaxHeight etc) of preset in AWS elastic trans coding

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, video, amazon-elastic-transcoder

Using aws elastic transcoder in out ongong project.
i would like get aws elastic transcoder preset id's meta data, about MaxWidth, MaxHeight ete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution :**
Follow this link - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elastictranscoder/read-preset.html

**Steps :**

1. Install aws cli in your system
2. aws cli configure using key
3. aws elastictranscoder read-preset --id (1351620000001-500020) // you will get details